# Spark - Read csv file with quote

Tags: apache-spark

I have a CSV file which has data contained in double quotes (").

> "0001", "A",  "001", "2017/01/01 12"
>
> "0001", "B", "002", "2017/01/01 13"

I would like to read only pure data (without " symbol).

```
spark.read
 .option("encoding", encoding)
 .option("header", header)
 .option("quote", quote)
 .option("sep", sep)
```

Other options work well, but only quote seems not work properly. It load with quote symbol ("). How should I take this symbol off from loaded data.

---

dataframe.show result

```
+----+----+------+---------------+
| _c0| _c1|   _c2|             _c3|
+----+----+------+---------------+
|0001| "A"| "001"| "2017/01/01 12"|
|0001| "B"| "002"| "2017/01/01 13"|
+----+----+------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use option quote as below

```
option("quote", "\"")
```

If you have an extra space between your two data as "abc", "xyz", than you need to use

`option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", true)`

Hope this helps

Comment: `option("quote", "\"")` did nothing for me until I also added `option("escape", "\"")` to reflect the CSV syntax where quotes inside quotes are escaped with quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a sample program using databicks api and tried it on your dataset

please check below code to read csv file

```
val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", true)
    .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", true)
    .load("src/test/resources/test")

 df.show()
+-----+------+-----+
|first|second|third|
+-----+------+-----+
|    A|   001|  CCC|
|    B|   002|  DDD|
+-----+------+-----+
```