# spark data read with quoted string

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i am having the csv data file as given below
each line is terminated by a Carriage Return('\r')

but certain value of  text are multilined field having line delimiter as line feed ('\n'). how to use spark data source api option to handle these issue.

with [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyL1a.png)

Comment: Did you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274559/spark-read-csv-file-with-quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark 2.2.0 has added support for parsing multi-line CSV files. You can use following to read a csv with multi-line:

```
val df = spark.read
  .option("sep", ",")
  .option("quote", "")
  .option("multiLine", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .csv(file_name)
```