# SparkSession CSV load sometimes doesn't work

Tags: csv, apache-spark

I have 3 CSV files which are delimited by `;`

I am able to read 2 of these files with SparkSession CSV loader, but the third file causes an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. When I inspect the three files manually, it looks like they all adhere to the exact same format, so I'm having trouble figuring out what causes SparkSession's CSV loader to fail. It also looks like Spark is not offering me any ways to debug its CSV loader.

Here is the code which works for 2 out of 3 files:

```
spark
    .read
    .format("csv")
    .option("delimiter", ";")
    .load("data/bx/BX-Users.csv")
```

Part of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 62
at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numBytesForFirstByte(UTF8String.java:191)
at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numChars(UTF8String.java:206)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:253)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Part of `BX-Users.csv`:

```
"1";"nyc, new york, usa";"NULL"
"2";"stockton, california, usa";"18"
"3";"moscow, yukon territory, russia";"NULL"
"4";"porto, v.n.gaia, portugal";"17"
```

Comment: This is very difficult to answer without knowing what the files look like or the exact message / trace

Comment: Could be a problem with formatting e.g. Quote without matching terminating quote a mixture of unix and windows style line endings etc

Comment: @BruceMartin I edited OP to add part of stack trace and part of input data.

Comment: Check if the third file has any extra `;` inside the text of the second column. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274559/spark-read-csv-file-with-quote